# Typical PSNR values

Tags: image, image-processing, image-compression

In [Image Restoration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_restoration) problem, (still image not video image), why [Peak Signal-to-Noise Ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peak_signal-to-noise_ratio) (PSNR) should not be more than 50 or 55 dB? I got 63 dB and they say it is wrong. why and How it is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

If your pixels are represented using 8 bits per sample,  the maximum possible pixel value of the image is 255. `20*log10(255) = 48 dB` the [mean squared error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error) (MSE) of noise is not considered yet. The typical compression ratio of jpeg is no less than [7](http://icmsm2009.um.edu.my/filebank/published_article/1778/112.pdf). In that case the MSE is around 0.224, and the corresponding PSNR is 54 dB. So you probably will not get the PSNR as high as 63 dB.

Comment: There are plenty of images in the world that are more than 8 bits per sample, but you make a good point.